# How can I merge two DataFrames of different length on the basis of common values?

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, nan

I have two DataFrames

```
df1

UNIQUE NUMBER   NAME    
1               John    
2               Sarah   
3               Luke    
4               Bob     
5               Annah
```

```
df2

UNIQUE NUMBER   COLOR
1               blue
3               red    
5               purple
```

In the dataset I have, the UNIQUE NUMBERS correspond to both the NAMES and the COLORS, meaning that e.g. John is associated to both number 1 and color blue.

I'd like to merge `df1` and `df2` on the basis of the unique numbers, to get `df_final`:

```
df_final

UNIQUE NUMBER   NAME    COLOR
1               John    blue
2               Sarah   NaN
3               Luke    red
4               Bob     NaN
5               Annah   purple
```

Given that the two DataFrames have different lengths, the `merge` function doesn't seem to be  applicable.
Is it possible to create a DataFrame like this?

Comment: A merge doesn't require at all the inputs to have the same shape. Just use `df1.merge(df2, on='UNIQUE NUMBER', how='left')`